# Django QuerySet Lookup Fails When Testing for Value "Local"

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet which returns a list of user-defined tags.  In some cases, I'd like to exclude any of the tags that start with the word "Local", but this seems to be causing me problems.

The following examples work when I'm testing for other values (like HVAC below):

```
queryset = queryset.exclude(tags__tag__tag_name__icontains = 'HVAC')
queryset = queryset.exclude(tags__tag__tag_name__istartswith = 'HVAC')
```

but when I try the same with "Local", it excludes everything, not just the values that contain or start with the word "Local".  Both examples below exclude everything:

```
queryset = queryset.exclude(tags__tag__tag_name__icontains = 'Local')
queryset = queryset.exclude(tags__tag__tag_name__istartswith = 'Local')
```

As an additional note, the following does work, but it only excludes that exact value and I can't anticipate / list all of the values that start with "Local":

`queryset = queryset.exclude(tags__tag__tag_name = 'Local 123')`

My best guess is that "Local" is a reserved word in python?  Any ideas on ways around this or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What if you append a space to Local, such as with `queryset = queryset.exclude(tags__tag__tag_name__icontains = 'Local ')`?

Comment: @MattCremeens Yeah, I thought that might help too, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: The `.exclude(..)` works different than a `.filter(..)`. Now you exclude all *model* objects that have at least one tag with `'Local'` in it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem interesting, thank you.  It seems like filter is doing the same thing - is this what you mean? `queryset = queryset.filter(~Q(tags__tag__tag_name__icontains = 'Local))`

Comment: Yes, point is that the negation of an existential quantifier, is the universal quantifier of the negated predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly the right way to deal with this issue, but since per @WillemVanOnsem it seems like I was excluding all model objects that have at least one tag with 'Local' in it (when using both exclude and filter as far as I can tell), instead I ended up creating a new list of all values that don't contain "Local" and returning that list instead of the original queryset.

```
newQueryset = list()

for item in list(queryset):
    if not 'local' in str(item['tags__tag__tag_name']).lower():
        newQueryset.append(item)

return newQueryset
```